# Trying to add a function to an already existing PHP Library

Tags: php

I am trying to add a function to an already existing php lib (which is not maintained anymore).

What I am trying to achieve is to be able to align the text to center/justify/left/right align.

Here is the git link of the library.

https://github.com/armagedan/thaana_text_render_php

Here is where I went so far.

```
//Creating property
//So by default, this will be centered

private $textAlign = 'center';


public function __construct($fontPath=NULL, $fontName=NULL, $fontSize=NULL, $textColor=NULL, $textAlpha=NULL, $textLineSpacing=NULL, $bgColor=NULL, $bgAlpha=NULL, $shadowOffset=NULL, $shadowColor=NULL, $shadowAlpha=NULL, $textAlign =NULL)
    {
        // Initialize with specified defaults:
        if (!empty($fontPath)) $this->setFontPath($fontPath);
        if (!empty($fontName)) $this->setFont($fontName);
        if (!empty($fontSize)) $this->setFontSize($fontSize);
        if (!empty($textColor)) $this->setTextColor($textColor, $textAlpha);
        if (!empty($textLineSpacing)) $this->setTextLineSpacing($textLineSpacing);
        if (!empty($bgColor)) $this->setBgColor($bgColor, $bgAlpha);
        if (!empty($shadowOffset)) $this->setShadow($shadowOffset, $shadowColor, $shadowAlpha);

        //This one I added
        if (!empty($textAlign )) $this->setAlignment($textAlign);
    }
```

And here is the function:

```
public function setAlignment($textAlign=NULL)
    {
        //What to do here?
        //So basically if the $textAlignment is null, then use the default one correct? Else use the user defined one?
    }
```

So what I am trying to do is add a function called `setAlignment` which will set the alignment of the text to left/center/right etc... Like microsoft word and so on. But I do not know where to continue from here. I want the last parameter of the Constructor to have the alignment options.

Comment: Well, how should the alignment be achieved? Typically and preferable this should be done using CSS classes, so the PHP part would be to annotate those classes to the HTML elements. And you will have to add the classes to the existing CSS files, whether they are static or dynamically created.

Comment: And also you should think twice if it is a good idea to invest into a library that is not maintained any more: there is a reason for that. It might not be usable in current versions of PHP and might contain security or logical bugs that are not fixed any more. Except you yourself have the knowledge and are willing to maintain the library from now on...

Comment: If the library isn't maintained anymore, just fork it and change what you need in it and use your implementation instead. But as @arkascha points out, it might be better to look for a library that is maintained.

Comment: Yes I agree with that. So far, this seems to be working with the latest php (7.2 as of now) and does not seem to have any problems and that is why I wanted to update this/Edit this. The problem with using CSS classes is that this library is used in controllers. In the sense, there is no requirement for HTML to begin with. This library basically outputs the text as an image. That is why I needed help. Basically you just write a text and it will output it as an image wit a bounding box. But I want to be able to have aligning option.